# Group action is transitive. Verify my proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $\phi : G \times G/K \to G/K$ be a group action defined by $\phi(a,gK) = agK.$ This action is obviously transitive because this amounts to asking if there is an $a \in G$ such that

$a\cdot g_1K = g_2K \iff \phi(a,g_1K) \stackrel{?}{=} g_2 K \iff a \dot g_1 = g_2$

Such an $a = g_2g_1^{-1}$, so that $ag_1 \in g_2 K.$ So this action is transitive.

Comment: Yes....and the question is...?

Comment: @DonAntonio, no that's it, I just want someone else to confirm my statement. That is the question, thanks.

Comment: Good, so you did just fine.